# Calculate frequencies in MICE dataset

Tags: r, database, imputation, r-mice

I have inputted an example dataset, e.g., *mtcars*:

```
    data(mtcars)
    library(mice)
    imp <- mice(mtcars,
                seed=123,
                m=5,
                maxit=10)
```

- Let's suppose I want to calculate the *[pooled means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance)* for disp, hp, and other variables.
  How can I do it? How can I calculate the *pooled frequencies*?
- If I want to perform a *pooled* t-test or chi square (e.g., `vs` and `am`), what code should I use? Should I use "with()"? What would  an example be?

I am having troubles since it is the first time I would be using "with()".

Answer (score 0):

First, `mtcars` is not a good dataset to use with imputation examples, since `mtcars` contains no `NA` values. I will use `nhanes` from the `mice` package for example.

You can use syntax from Heyman and Eekhout's *Applied Missing Data Analysis*. [Chapter 5 describes how to pool means and standard deviations](https://bookdown.org/mwheymans/bookmi/data-analysis-after-multiple-imputation.html). You can edit Heyman and Eekhout's code, using `table` instead of `mean` to get the frequencies. I have made those edits and created a function called `mice_func()` that does this easily.

```
library(mice); library(dplyr)
data("nhanes")
set.seed(123)
myimp <- mice(nhanes, seed = 123, m = 5, maxit = 10, printFlag = FALSE)
myvs <- c("age", "bmi", "chl")

mice_func <- function(imp, vs){
  
  impdat <- mice::complete(imp, action = "long", include = FALSE)
  
  z <- lapply(as.list(vs), function(x){
    x = as.name(x)
    pool_freq <- with(impdat, by(impdat, .imp, function(y) c(
      table(y[[x]])
    )))
    Reduce("+", pool_freq)/length(pool_freq)
  }) %>%
    setNames(as.list(vs))
  
  return(z)
}

mice_func(myimp, myvs)
```

Calculating t-tests and such is also included in Chapter 5.

```
# Conduct an independent t-test via lm in each imputed dataset
fit.t.test <- with(data = myimp, exp = lm(age ~ bmi + chl))
t.test.estimates <- pool(fit.t.test)
summary(t.test.estimates)
```